# Aggregating a column by the same column

Tags: r, data.table

Why the conventional syntax for column aggregation in `data.table` `dt[, sum(x), by = "y"]` doesn't work if we refer to the same column in `j` and `by`, i.e., `dt[, sum(x), by = "x"]`?

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(x = sample(c(1:10), 20, T), y = sample(letters[1:4], 20, T))
setorderv(dt, "y")
```

I want to sum `x` by `x` but the following doesn't work, it merely replicates the `x` column:

```
> dt[, sum(x, na.rm = T), by = "x"]
     x V1
 1:  4  4
 2: 10 10
 3:  3  3
 4:  9  9
 5:  7  7
 6:  1  1
 7:  8  8
 8:  6  6
 9:  2  2
10:  5  5
```

Now if I do:

```
> dt[, .(res = lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = T)), by = 'x', .SDcols = "x"] 
     x res
 1:  4  12
 2: 10  30
 3:  3   9
 4:  9   9
 5:  7  21
 6:  1   1
 7:  8  24
 8:  6   6
 9:  2   2
10:  5   5
```

That works.

On the other hand, the following aggregation works (as expected) if the `by` argument is a column different than the one used to aggregate in `j`:

```
> dt[, sum(x, na.rm = T), by = "y"]
   y V1
1: a 38
2: b 38
3: c 17
4: d 26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every column in `by=` is reduced to a length of one, instead of redundantly duplicating the values out to the length of the group, `.N`, taking up more memory. You can still calculate the sum by multiplying by `.N`, though:

```
dt[, x*.N, by=x]
```

... or the full-length vector can be added to `.SD` (though this should never be necessary):

```
dt[, sum(.SD$x), by=x, .SDcols="x"]
```

`.SD` is the "Subset of Data" for a given `by=` group. See `?.SD` or `?.N` for details.

Comment: (I looked for a dupe here and on gh and couldn't find any... happy to delete if one is found, though.)

Comment: Thanks. But why reducing the column in `by` to a length of one causes the column to duplicate?

Comment: @JdeMello Sorry, I meant that the alternative required for your sum to work would require duplication. You can see the difference between how x is treated here `dt[, x, by=x]` versus how it would need to be treated for your sum to work: `dt[, rep(x, .N), by=x]`